# How to package a maven multi-module properly?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-3

I'm building a multi-module rest service with Maven and Spring Boot that will be published on a WebLogic Server, and I'm a bit confuse about how to configure the packaging of the application modules.

My current structure is:

/application

   /main (main mehtod for spring-boot)

   /api

   /service

   /dao

The parent project (application folder) is set up as pom packaging, but child projects I'm not sure how to configure it. I believe the correct way would be packaging like .jar file, but i saw some examples on the internet of Java projects with Maven multi-modules defined as war.

can someone tell me what's the correct way to define the child modules packaging in this case?

**My parent pom:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.radarveicular</groupId>
  <artifactId>radarveicular-application</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>
    </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>radarveicular-api</module>
    <module>radarveicular-service</module>
    <module>radarveicular-main</module>
    <module>radarveicular-dao</module>
  </modules>

  <build>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

</project>
```

**main pom:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.radarveicular</groupId>
    <artifactId>radarveicular-application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>radarveicular-main</artifactId>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>com.radarveicular</groupId>
            <artifactId>radarveicular-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**api pom:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.radarveicular</groupId>
        <artifactId>radarveicular-application</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>radarveicular-api</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.radarveicular</groupId>
            <artifactId>radarveicular-service</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**service pom:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.radarveicular</groupId>
        <artifactId>radarveicular-application</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>radarveicular-service</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.radarveicular</groupId>
            <artifactId>radarveicular-dao</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

**dao pom:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.radarveicular</groupId>
        <artifactId>radarveicular-application</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>radarveicular-dao</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.30</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that **your parent `pom.xml` shouldn't handle your spring boot project**. Meaning, you should have this in it :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

I recommend that your `pom.xml` parent only handles your modules and dependencies as `pom` packaging :

**Packaging**

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

**Modules**

```
<modules>
    <module>radarveicular-api</module>
    <module>radarveicular-service</module>
    <module>radarveicular-main</module>
    <module>radarveicular-dao</module>
</modules>
```

Then, you will have your module `radarveicular-main` with the spring boot parent :

**Parent**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

**Packaging**

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

I hope this will help you. =)

Comment: In this case i will point for two parents in my radarveicular-main pom? radarveicular-application and spring-boot parents?

Comment: Your module can't have 2 parents. Your `radarveicular-main` will only have `spring-boot-parent` as a parent. Then your `parent` will use `module` to package the all project.

Answer (score 1):

I feel your question is more towards designing part of multi module.

Multi module management of application can depend on various things.

1. One thing could be if you want to deploy each sub module as separate module/service based, which can be turned off/on based on need. In that case it would help you if you build each of module as separate war and deploy them separately.
2. If you have to deploy it as a single war than most straight forward would to create all dependent modules as jar and include them in parent project. In this way a single war will be deployed.
3. You can have a hybrid approach of above two.

Hopefully i have understood your question correctly. :)

Happy coding!!

Comment: I have a question here.. Following the first option and deploy individually each module, how this process works? I need to build the same folder structure in my local server and deploy each module in the respective folder?